# Let an exception raise itself

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x

Is it possible to let an exception raise itself, in its own class instance ?
Something like this:

```
class Error(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        if some stuff:
            pass
        elif some other stuff:
            # re-raise myself

raise Error()
```

I've tried to use `raise self` but it returns an error ; also, I don't see any attribute to the exception class that seems to be linked to this.

**Edit**

If I want to do this, it is because I've attached some special methods to my `Exception` class, which format the error message to be printed depending of what parameters are passed to the exception. I could have done the formatting job in a separate object, but as it is only used by the exception, it seemed to me natural to attach it to the exception class itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "returns an error"? I hope you don't mean that it raises an exception.

Comment: You can't re-raise the exception because it hasn't happened yet - the exception object is in the process of being built.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: I mean `TypeError: object is not callable`, which is not related to my `Error` class

Comment: This sounds dangerously close to creating an exception loop.

Comment: So what's the alternative ? Defining a second exception which would raise the first one ?

Comment: @doukremt: Then you're doing something wrong. http://codepad.org/aYPV1fD8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* raise an exception in the `__init__` of an exception type, just like you can do so in any type’s `__init__`. This however will prevent the object from being created—instead, the exception is thrown.

So your original `raise Error()` will not be called at all, and the exception object you wanted to create there is never created. Instead, you will just get an exception because the object you created (`Error`) couldn’t be created.

So you lose all the information about the actual `raise` which you wanted to execute.

As such, no, don’t do that.

In any way this also seems to be a very odd way to do have an exception type. The exception object *itself* should not be dependent on any outside factors, and `some stuff` does appear to be something magic here. What is it you are actually trying to solve here?

What might help understanding, would be writing your `raise Error()` like this:

```
e = Error()
raise e
```

So you first create an exception object, and only then you actually raise it. So inside the `__init__` of that type, you cannot *reraise* it as it has never been raised yet. But there is no need to reraise it anyway, because you are still raising it afterwards. So again: What are you trying to do? Do you want the exception object itself to be capable of *preventing* the raise on certain conditions (hence the `pass` in your code)?

### Update

> it is because I've attached some special methods to my Exception class, which format the error message to be printed depending of what parameters are passed to the exception.

That does not justify raising an exception in the `__init__` of the type *at all*. You can easily format your exception message all you want without having to raise the exception in the class itself. For example:

```
>>> class Error (Exception):
        def __init__ (self, msg, rightAligned = False, spacedOut = False):
            if spacedOut:
                msg = ' '.join(msg)
            if rightAligned:
                msg = msg.rjust(72)
            Exception.__init__(self, msg)

>>> raise Error('Random message')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    raise Error('Random message')
Error: Random message
>>> raise Error('Random message', True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    raise Error('Random message', True)
Error:                                                           Random message
>>> raise Error('Random message', False, True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    raise Error('Random message', False, True)
Error: R a n d o m   m e s s a g e
```

As you can see, I can change the exception message in whatever way I want without having to raise an exception in the class.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** This answer should not have been accepted. [poke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16203252/9990) address the heart of the problem and presents a correct solution.

A self-raising class seems to work fine for me:

```
>>> class Err(Exception):
...   def __init__(self):
...     Exception.__init__(self, 'gulp!')
...     raise self
... 
>>> raise Err()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
__main__.Err: gulp!
```

I'm not a Python language export, so this might be some weird half-aborted class that doesn't behave itself very well. Caveat emptor.

The burning question: why would you do this? Is there some reason you don't want to use the standard Python idiom of explicitly raising the exception after constructing it?

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your immediate error:

```
raise self.__class__
```

However then you have a potential for infinite recursion.  what if "some other stuff" is always true?